# Manipulating and positioning cells in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I am working to print this table

[image]

but what I have is this

[image]

the Ave and the percentages should be below of the criteria which are (Exam, Laoratory, Quiz and Recitation)

here is my code so far:

```
$sql_criteria = mysql_query("
    SELECT DISTINCT criteria,
           percentage 
      FROM tb_equivalent
     WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' 
       AND description = '$desc' 
       AND subj_code = '$code' 
       AND term = '$term'
");

$criteria = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_criteria)) {
    $criteria[] = $row['criteria'];

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Cell(35,5,$row['criteria'],1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(17.5,5,'Ave',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(17.5,5,$row['percentage']."%",1,'','C');
}

$pdf->Cell(35,10,'Grade',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'Remark',1,0,'C');
```

Any help with my problem will be appreciated, and kindly... please point out what is wrong in my codes thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_criteria)){
    $criteria[] = $row['criteria'];
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Cell(35,5,$row['criteria'],1,'','C');
    $x = $pdf->GetX(); // get current x pos
    $y = $pdf->GetY(); // get current y pos
    $pdf->SetXY($x-35, $y+5); // move pointer back to start of and under criteria cell
    $pdf->Cell(17.5,5,'Ave',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(17.5,5,$row['percentage']."%",1,'','C');
    $pdf->SetXY($x, $y); // set pointer back to end of criteria cell
}
```

Comment: hi sir thanks for the response and your code works but its funny it became like this -> http://i.imgur.com/xlyRQwv.png XD

Comment: Ah, that should have been $y+5 not -